# Black screen after installation of a command-line version of ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, xorg, graphics, troubleshooting, framebuffer

I just installed ubuntu 12.04 (command line version) on an old machine (athlon 1,2 GHz, 1GB RAM, [SiS] 65x/M650/740 graphics). When I boot the screen turns black after the BIOS messages. Even grub doesn't appear.

The system reboots if I press `Ctrl+Alt+Del`. `Ctrl+Alt+F2`... doesn't bring my to any `tty`.

However I can access the machine via `ssh` (I installed it in expert mode and selected open-ssh-server during installation).

In spite of the black screen I tried to type in blind my username and password. Then I did `touch test` and I was able to verify via `ssh` that this created a file named `test`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

**Edit**:

I insalled `xinit` and started blind `startx` but there was no X session, only a black screen. However I can verify via ssh that X was running.

Here is my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`: http://pastebin.com/RiZBCVfD
Here is my `dmesg`: http://pastebin.com/KFBdPHS9
Here is my `syslog`: http://pastebin.com/W9S0V6T8
Here is the output of `lsmod`: http://pastebin.com/nzwASEXq

Comment: Initially I would recommend trying a reinstall as you haven't actually begun using the system and wouldn't lose anything.

Comment: I guess doing the same install prodecure I would end up with the same problem.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the SIS on board graphics, but I don't know what I could change..

Comment: Provided your first install didn't have any problems ;)

Comment: I have a laptop with SIS onboard and that runs ubuntu just fine.

Comment: Up to now I had ubuntu 9.04 on this machine, now I installed ubuntu 12.04 on a freshly formatted hard drive. Wait I have full `dd` image of my hard drive with the 9.04 system. Perhaps I can lookup some configuratin things there but I have no idea what I should look for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem completely by commenting out the line `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` in `/etc/defaults/grub` and doing `sudo update-grub` and `sudo reboot`.

Comment: That's great to hear, please mark your answer as the 'accepted answer' to help other people who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+alt+F7 is the means to switch to the standard GUI that I have seen. If that fails review what version you installed and ensure you wrote the desktop version, not the server (headless) version.

Comment: As stated in the title of the post in installed the command line version without GUI.

Comment: I just tried to install `x` via `sudo aptitude install xinit` and start it blind via `startx` to see if the problem has something to do with the framebuffer or something like that, but there is no X session, just a black screen (thoug `X` is running as I can verify via `ssh`)